# Trouble with using a simple boolean

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-statements

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but Im completely new to this and just trying my hand.
My code is stuck....after this point, the program ends, no matter whether a 1 or 2 is selected. I know its something simple im missing....Any input is appreciated.  I have copy and pasted the section in which I think the problem lies below.

```
    System.out.println("Is this information correct? Enter 1 if it is correct, and 2 to change");
    Scanner inputCorrect = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pick = inputCorrect.nextInt();
    boolean isCorrect = false;

    while (isCorrect = false){

          while (!(pick == 1) && (!(pick ==2)))
              System.out.println("That is not a valid entry please try again");

              if (pick == 1){

                  isCorrect = true;
              }

              if (pick == 2){
                  System.out.println("Enter 1 to change your name, 2 to change your age or 3 to change your gender");
                  Scanner inputChange = new Scanner(System.in);
                  int change = inputChange.nextInt();

                    if (change ==1){
                        Scanner inputNewName = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Enter the correct name: ");
                        String correctedName = inputNewName.next();
                        you.setName(correctedName);
                        System.out.println(you);
                        isCorrect = true;
                    }

                    if (change ==2) {
                        Scanner inputNewAge = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Enter the correct age: ");
                        int correctedAge = inputNewAge.nextInt();
                        you.setAge(correctedAge);
                        System.out.println(you);
                        isCorrect = true;

                    }

                    if (change == 3) {
                        Scanner inputNewGender = new Scanner (System.in);
                        System.out.println("Enter the correct gender: ");
                        char correctedGender = inputNewGender.next().charAt(0);
                        you.setGender(correctedGender);
                        System.out.println(you);
                        isCorrect = true;

                    }   
          }     
      }
```

Comment: Noob better try to do some research before asking a question on SO

Comment: Some people use [yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) to avoid this issue. `while(false == isCorrect)`

Comment: 2 upvotes? Really? Questions like this are found all over SO.

Comment: Ha! Yoda conditions. That's awesome, never heard it called that before.

Comment: @nickecarlo doesn't mean it's not a good question. I've had issues where the issue is very simple, but I'm so deep in the code that I didn't notice the problem.

Comment: If exactly the same question has been asked about 3 million times then it is not just not a good question...its a terrible question that shows no effort at researching the issue.

Comment: Don't compare `boolean`s to `true` or `false`. Use `if (condition)` or `while(!condition)` etc. `if (condition == true)` is less readable.

Comment: I wonder how many of these bugs would never-have-been if `x = ..` was a restricted production in conditionals - either making it a statement and avoiding this production entirely or requiring that it be expressed as `if((x = y))` or similar. I guess that's what *code/style checkers* are for. I suppose the same can be argued for String/Object equality testing .. *uhg*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your while loop

```
while (isCorrect = false){
```

You are using the assignment operator, `=`, so it's always false.

You want the comparison operator `==` to compare if the values are the same.

```
while (isCorrect == false){
```

Since it's already a `boolean`, you may want to just use `isCorrect` by itself:

```
while (!isCorrect)
```

Comment: ...and possibly use: while (!isCorrect) instead

Comment: @Mena - Yep, was getting to it!

Comment: I always recommend the latter syntax (`!isCorrect`) as it avoids this potential problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an assignment operator in your while statement expression which will always evaluate to `false`. Use the `==` operator instead to compare the `boolean`:

```
while (isCorrect == false){
```

or better

```
while (!isCorrect){
```

Comment: better: `while(!isCorrect)`

Comment: `if(stillTyping == true)` ??

Answer (score 2):

You can help yourself in the future by doing it this way:

```
 while( false == isCorrect )
```

This will throw a compile error if you mistype the equality operator.

Comment: I find `!isCorrect` does a better job *in Java*. In languages like C, Yoda conditionals are more important because `(x = 42)` also evaluates to a true value.

Comment: @user2246674 - But it also applies for `if(3 = x)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Not in Java - `if` *requires* that the expression is typed `boolean`. The result of `(x = 3)` is `3` which is an `int` and thus *not compatible* with a `boolean` - it will be a compiler type error.